# react props not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The problem is that state is staying undefined. The first console log of nextProps.userid is showing the correct userid but it is not changing state and the second console log comes back null.

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: this.props.userid,
    };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    console.log('PROFILE USERID', nextProps.userid)
    const userid = nextProps.userid
    this.setState({user:userid})
    console.log('PROFILE USERID 2', this.state.user)
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous. So you cannot expect the value of state to be changed immediately after `setState`. If you log your state right after the `setState` then it will show you previous state. If you want to see the updated value of state then try passing a callback to `setState` like this

```
this.setState({user:userid}, () => {
    console.log('PROFILE USERID 2', this.state.user)
});
```